# How do I take a 3d dimensional array and convert it into a model?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, model, 3d

I'm using Open CV and I'm able to extract multidimensional data from and image with my codes but what would be an easy way to display it? I have a 3D array:

```
line start [x] [y] [z]
line end   [x] [y] [z]
```

Anything in between the lines will be filled with a solid flat surface.

Is there some kind of function I can  use to easily display a 3d image given these points or whatever other points I'm missing?

Such as this pseudo code:

```
display_3d(x,y,z,angle)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Also I'm using C++.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand correctly but why do you have 3D array ???

- array of 3D points representing surface is usually 1D array of 3D points:

  ```
          float points[n][3];
  // not float points[nx][ny][nz] !!!
  ```

I am not CV user so I will stick to (OpenGL) rendering, but you can use any other render instead.

1.if the points represents **concave flat surface**

- on **single plane**!!!
- and are **in the order** (not mixed up)
- then you can use GL_TRIANGLE_FAN or anything similar in other renders.

  ```
  float points[n]={ {x,y,z},{x,y,z},...};
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
  glVertex3fv(points[0]);
  glVertex3fv(points[1]);
  glVertex3fv(points[2]);
  ...
  glVertex3fv(points[n-1]);
  glEnd();
  ```

2.if not then you have to triangulate your data

- it is not an easy task but there are some libs out there that do it.
- not sure if OpenCV can do that too, look for triangulation functions (ears drop,etc)
- I prefer my own triangulation routines (better for debugging and also for additional polygon info) but a little hard to code it efficiently and correctly when you not used to used algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) of your points which  means finding non-ambiguous and efficient representation of a set of points. Once you do that you *will* need to triangulate your mesh, usually using [delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/) provides such functionality.