# Drawing 3D polygons as a mesh

Tags: opengl, graphics, computational-geometry

I have a list of 3D points, forming a 3D polygon. They are actually N>2 lines drawn by user.

I would like to create a mesh from this polygon and draw the polygon with texture.
For this purpose, i need to create triangles from the surface formed by the polygon.
How i can perform this triangulation? 
Are there any libraries i can use?

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445927/how-do-i-take-a-3d-dimensional-array-and-convert-it-into-a-model/21111053#21111053

Comment: Are your points ordered?  That is, do you know how the points should be connected by edges and faces?  Or is it just a collection of points?  If the latter, see @concept3d 's post.

Comment: It is actually the first option. i have the full path of the perimeter

Answer (score 0):

You should first turn the 3D problem into a 2D one by finding the plane of the face. You can use three vertices (forming two vectors) for this purpose (avoid taking too close or too much aligned).

Then you will project every vertex onto that plane. This can be done by creating an orthogonal coordinates frame from the two vectors using vector calculus or equivalently Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Perform the change of coordinates and drop Z.

Triangulation by "ear clipping" isn't that difficult to implement (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

After 2D triangulation, you will transform the vertices back to 3D coordinates.

Comment: I also thought of this kind of solution, but it would work well only for shapes that are 2D or "almost 2D". For curves it will not work well because it might create too large triangles.

Comment: what curves ?? your question is about polygons !